# How to use def variable as condition of an if controller - JMeter

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter

I have such define inside a JSR223 Assertion:

```
def code = 123
```

is there a way to use it as condition of my if controller?

I tried with

```
${code}=='123'
```

but it does not work.

Here is the Thread Group:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add code as a JMeter variable:

```
vars.put("code", code.toString());
```

And then check with [jexl3](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or groovy in If Controller:

```
${__jexl3(${code} == 123)}
```

Reference from [If Controller component](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)

> For example, previously one could use the condition: ${__jexl3(${VAR} == 23)}

Also you can see [String in Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation):

> def greeting = "Hello ${name}"
>
> assert greeting.toString() == 'Hello Guillaume'

Comment: it works like a charm, thank you! Please could u reference the doc u took it from?

Comment: add reference to doc

Answer (score 1):

You can check which variables are defined in JMeter using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination, if the variable is not set - you can use the same approach to see where it got "lost". JSR223 Test Elements errors normally can be found in *jmeter.log* file.

Coming back to your question:

1. You need to store your `code` into [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance like:

   ```
   def code = 123
   vars.putObject('code', 123)
   ```
2. Amend your If Controller's condition to look like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.getObject('code') == 123,)}
   ```

More information: [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)